# Function Template Specialization with Forward Declared Type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, c++14, forward-declaration

Haven't been able to quite find a duplicate.

Is it possible to forward-declare the type used in a function specialization?

Consider the following code:

**in .h**

```
template <typename T>
T* Foo()
{
    //generic implementation
}

template<>
class SpecialT* Foo<class SpecialT>();
```

**in .cpp**

```
#include "SpecialT.h"

template<>
SpecialT* Foo<SpecialT>()
{
    //specialized implementation
}
```

Is there any syntax in which the above is possible and doesn't result in a slew of compiler errors (C2910, C2909, C2768, etc.)?

This of course compiles if "SpecialT.h" is included in the template header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple workaround is to simply put the forward declaration on its own line:

```
class SpecialT;
template<>
SpecialT* Foo<SpecialT>();
```

[VS 2015 on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/UnH4iV) accepts it just fine.

Comment: Oh, facepalm! I'm a buffoon for not trying that myself. Thank you.

Comment: @Rotem In your defense, this is a work around an MSVC bug.